# Disable or slow down fling behaviour in LinearSnapHelper

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When I use a `LinearSnapHelper` with a `RecyclerView` and I fling the `RecyclerView` the list scrolls way too far too fast. Can I change this behavior or disable it completely?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use PagerSnapHelper instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `ViewPager` like behaviour, you can try using [`PagerSnapHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PagerSnapHelper) instead of the `LinearSnapHelper`